# Impossible to position horizontal line in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, position

I'm getting a little problem with my **HTML page**. I would like to set my **horizontal line** to the left side.

Up to now, my line is always situated in the center of my page and I don't reach to move this line between my text.

This is my little **HTML script** :

```
<html>
    <head>
    {% load staticfiles %}

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/Base.css' %}"/>

    <style>

            body {
                font-family: Courier New, Courier, monospace;
                text-align: justify;
                list-style-type: none;
            }

            .header {
                 line-height: 80%;
                 margin:left;
            }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class = "header">
            <h3> Département </h3> 
            <p></p> 
            (variable)
            <hr align="left" width="10%"> 
            <h3> Commune </h3> 
            <p></p> 
            (variable)
        </div>
</html>
```

And my **HTML page** looks like :

[image]

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try set `display: inline-block;` to your `<hr>` to render the horizontal line as an inline element with block properties.

Also make sure that your markup and CSS is valid! E.g. a CSS rule `margin: left;` is wrong. Right would be: `margin-left: 10px;`.

Plus: It's not recommended to use inline styles, as the code becomes less maintainable. Try defining the rules in the CSS section of your HTML document or a separate CSS file.

```css
.header {
  line-height: 80%;
}
hr {
  width: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h3> Département </h3> 
  <p>(variable)</p>

  <hr>
  <h3> Commune </h3> 
  <p>(variable)</p>

</div>
```

Comment: According to `html2pdf library` (I'm using it with my Django Project), CSS `display` doesn't work very well. I have to find another way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Just add **(variable)** text inside any HTML element. So that **hr** tag will come below it.

```html
<html>
<head>
{% load staticfiles %}

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/Base.css' %}"/>

<style>

        body {
            font-family: Courier New, Courier, monospace;
            text-align: justify;
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        .header {
             line-height: 80%;
 
        }

</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class = "header">
        <h3> Département </h3> 
        <p></p> 
        <span>(variable)</span>
        <hr align="left" width="10%"> 
        <h3> Commune </h3> 
        <p></p> 
        <span>(variable)</span>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: How is this an answer? It just copies OP code into a snippet, and no explanation or anything.

Comment: @PeterB Check carefully. I have changed something in that.

Comment: Then it is still a bad answer, don't make it a riddle.